# Why do I have Thread started: <Thread pool> appearing without explanation in Xamarin IOs

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, threadpool

My code is working but I have this who appear in my Console, is there a problem in my code or is it normal, I develop an app IOs on Xamarin using Xaml and C#

I think that each time I open a page or Initialise an element, it showed up many times, how can I fix that ?

```
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #22
Thread started:  #23
Thread started:  #24
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #25
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #26
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #27
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #28
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #29
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #30
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #31
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #32
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #33
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #34
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #35
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #36
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #37
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #38
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #39
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #40
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #41
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #42
```

`InitializeComponent();`

Comment: Why does it need fixing? Why does it bother you if thread pool threads start?

Comment: As far as i know this is normal for iOS